# Converting models into a list of ViewModels

Tags: c#, beginner, generics, iterator, mvvm

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<PrimaryKey, ModelType>
{
    //Some base fields

    public static List<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable<ModelType> collection) 
        where T : BaseViewModel<PrimaryKey, ModelType>, new()
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        if (collection != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                var view = new T();
                view.Value = item;

                list.Add(view);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Of course, it works because it requires to I set a generic type.

```
var list = GroupViewModel.Convert<GroupViewModel>(model);
```

There is `GroupViewModel` extends from `BaseViewModel`. But how can I reduce this generic casting to it will get `GroupViewModel` type automaticaly when I call it so: `var list = GroupViewModel.Convert(model);`.
Is it possible? Just I learn C# only.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly I think [this answer from StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types) could give you some helpful information

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what to say more then:

- make it an extension and return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead by using linq

do you mean something like this?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Convert<T>(this IEnumerable<ModelType> modelTypes) 
    where T : BaseViewModel<PrimaryKey, ModelType>, new()
{
    return modelTypes.Select(x => new T { Value = x });    
}
```

use it:

```
var groupViewModels = modelTypes.Convert<GroupViewModel>().ToList();
```

Comment: It isn't that I wanted =) But I like this solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work! Although, I can't understand why C# can't get generic type in this expression.

Comment: @Шах with just _doesn't work_ we won't get any further...

Comment: "Although, I can't understand why C# can't get generic type in this expression."